# Google App Engine Java: Where is the source code of "CompiledCursor"?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I know that the source code for GAE's client lib is [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/).
Looking at the below page:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Cursor.java

.. I see this import on line 6:

```
import com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb.CompiledCursor;
```

Now, where is that class defined at? Searched the SVN, didn't find anything. I'm looking for its source code (in Java) in order to understand several internal things.

*By the way - what "Pb" stands for? See this a lot in GAE's code.*

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class isn't (currently) part of the released sources. This isn't because it needs to be hyper-secret or anytihng - it just includes internal implementation details that we haven't abstracted out for public release. Since it's an undocumented, internal implementation detail, it's probably not a high priority to clean it up and release the source. In this case (and to answer your other question), it's a compiled [Protocol Buffer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), so you wouldn't find the source particularly instructive anyway - it's machine generated.

Comment: Just realized you're from the GAE team - good to have someone like you around here! (: My final aim, of this question, is to be able to artificially create Cursor objects. I want to create several and pass them on to several tasks. Is it even possible to create my own Cursor object or is it strictly coming from the datastore?

Comment: @Poni Create the cursors based on what? The datastore issues them, and their content is an implementation detail.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough - create the cursors based on offset number, like a cursor which will start from 500th entity and another which will start from 1000th entity and so on. I have a feeling it's impossible but who knows. So, can I create custom Cursor somehow?

Comment: That is impossible - a cursor bookmarks a specific spot in the result set, not a result offset. Think of it like holding your place in the phone book by writing down the last name you tried, not by the page number it was on.

Comment: Like a linked-list? You mean it saves its last position as a pointer to an object, as we would in a linked-list?

Comment: @Poni No, I mean it saves its last position as a sort key - like recording that the last phone book entry you read was 'Jones, S'.

Comment: Is it planned to be published (the source code)? Because it's already 2017 and no news about that yet. And the SDK is still poorly written and almost unusable

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that class is part of the public API. As you can see, the package name of DatastorePb (com.google.**apphosting**.api) differs from the API package: com.google.**appengine**.api.

The class is in fact not even listed in the JavaDocs for the package: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/apphosting/api/package-summary.html, so I'd say the sources aren't public.

However, with Java being based on bytecode, it is possible to decompile the .class file (observe that this may be illegal in some countries. If I recall correctly, it is allowed in the US at least in situations like these).

The class can be found in the GAE SDK, under *sdk base*/lib/user/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-*version*.jar/com/google/apphosting/api/

Comment: I've noticed it's in another package - I hope someone else will have better answer for me.. and - I'm in Israel - law is a subjective matter haha! :) (joking, I'm a strict law follower!)

Comment: The law is only important if you get caught.. :) Also, I tried a google search for the package: http://www.google.se/search?q=%22package%20com.google.apphosting.api%22. Since the DatastorePb class must have that declaration in the sources, I see slim chances of the sources being found. Perhaps you could ask Google for the sources?

Comment: Anyone knows better than us please?